# Linking dependency to static library?

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, build, static-libraries

I have a small console application that makes use of the MySql C/C++ connector interface.
I'd like to make a static library out of the existing code and am wondering how (or if it is possible) to link the MySql C/C++ interface with my static library seeing as there is no "Link" tab in the properties dialog of the project.

I'd basically like to link my static library to a new project and have everything work as it did in my old console application.

Is there a way of doing this (without simply just linking the MySql C/C++ interface to the new project) or am I looking at this from the wrong angle? If so let me know what might be a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static library projects (i.e. that output a .lib file on a win32 environment) haven't a link tab because they're not meant to be linked when generating the output file.

Instead they concur, alongside with other .lib files, to resolve link-time dependencies in a project (e.g. executable) that requires linking.

To do what you want you just need to include the necessary headers and **make sure both your code and the C/C++ interface (which is also a lib file) are provided at link-time for the project that will use them and will be ultimately linked**